# Won't delete selected vertices

Tags: vertices

Blender won't let me delete vertices! I started from an edge group and used ctrl+ to expand the selection to multiple vertices. When I press "x" and try to delete them, the first time, it appears to do nothing! I selected the same vertices and tried again a few times, and only after a couple times did blender delete *some* of the selected vertices. Anyone know what's wrong?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm working on: 
[image]

I'm trying to use the Makeclothes add-on to edit clothing for a Makehuman model.

Comment: When the delete menu pops up which option are you using?

Comment: The first one, "vertices."

Comment: would help if you could upload the file

Comment: My best guess, there are duplicate faces, edges or vertices at that position. To get rid of them, in edit mode tap A once or twice till everything is selected and then press W and select "Remove Doubles"

Comment: To upload file use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. The available screenshot doesn't cover all the possible information. You could also attach screenshot per each action you describe in the question together with the file

Answer (score 0):

Another tip: As I was selecting a section of vertices to delete but they didn't seem to be deleting.  Turn X-Ray on might do the trick if using group selection if you are forgetting about vertices behind other vertices.

Alt+Z in Blender 3.x